# Interpreting EL expression containing HTML in JSF page

Tags: html, jsf, el, froala

I am trying to use Froala Editor, however I have a problem when trying to display something I have saved before (https://www.froala.com/wysiwyg-editor/docs#frontend)

The problem is that, having `#{article.body}` with the value`<p>aaaa</p>`:

- if I put in my facelets page `<div class="fr-view">#{article.body}</div>` I see on screen the text `<p>aaaa</p>` (which is incorrect)
- however if I put in my facelets page `<div class="fr-view"><p>aaaa</p></div>` I see `aaaa` (which is the correct text)

Any idea of why is this happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to tell JSF EL not to escape Bean's field value using `<h:outputText>` tag.

```
<div class="fr-view"><h:outputText value="#{article.body}" escape="false"/></div>
```